# Removable singularity for analytic function on the punctured disk where $|f'(z)| \leq 1/|z|$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that on the punctured disk $0 < |z| < 1, \ f(z)$ is analytic with its first derivative bounded by $$
  |\,f'(z)| \leq \frac{1}{|z|}.
$$

Show that $f$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$.

---

I suspect this question may have been answered elsewhere—perhaps someone could point me to an existing answer.

I suspect there may be a clever way to use the [Schwarz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma) or perhaps [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem).

Answer (score 3):

The hypotheses imply $f'(z)$ has at worst a pole of order $1$ at $0.$ So we can write

$$f'(z) = \frac{c}{z} +g(z)$$

for $0<|z|<1,$ where $g$ is analytic in $D(0,1).$ Now $g$ has an antiderivative $G$ in $D(0,1).$ It follows that

$$(f-G)'(z) = \frac{c}{z}, \,\, 0<|z|<1.$$

If $c\ne 0,$ we have discovered an antiderivative of $1/z$ in $\{0<|z|<1\}.$ Is that possible? Insert "no" here: ___.  Thus $c=0,$ leading to the desired conclusion.

Comment: Or $$c = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1/2} f'(z)\,dz = 0\,.$$

Comment: @MarkViola Fundamental theorem of calculus, essentially. The integral of a derivative over a closed curve is always $0$.

Comment: @MarkViola But $\frac{1}{z}$ isn't a derivative in any domain that has a loop winding about $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, I understand that $\log(z)$ is not analytic on $\mathbb{C}$.  I was wondering where you begin .  The problem statement is that $f$ is analytic on the punctured disk and that  $|f'(z)|\le \frac{1}{|z|}$.  So, did you begin with $f(z)=\frac cz+g(z)$ for some analytic function $g$?

Comment: @MarkViola We begin with $f$, which by assumption is holomorphic on the punctured unit disk. Hence $\int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1/2} f'(z)\,dz = 0$. Next we use the assumption about $f'$, which gives the decomposition in the answer. And then we use $\int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1/2} \frac{c}{z} + g(z)\,dz = 2\pi i c$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, I understand the order of the logic you used now.   Much appreciated.  And apology if my asking for the details inconvenienced you.

Comment: No problem @MarkViola. (My apologies to zhw. for the many notifications.)

Comment: No problem here gentlemen, and thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider the Laurent series of $f(z)$ and $f'(z)$ in the punctured disk:

$$ f(z) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} a_n z^n,\qquad f'(z)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}na_n z^{n-1}. $$
If we assume that some $a_n$ with $n<0$ is $\neq 0$, we have a violation of the inequality $\left|f'(z)\right|\leq \frac{1}{|z|}$ for some $z$ sufficiently close to the origin, since in such a case $z f'(z)$ has a singularity at the origin, which is either a pole or an essential singularity. In both cases $zf'(z)$ cannot stay bounded as $z\to 0$. It follows that the only non-zero coefficients are the ones with $n\geq 0$ and $f(z)$ is holomorphic over $|z|<1$.

Answer (score 1):

Note, applying L'Hopital's rule:

$$\lim_{z\to 0} zf(z)=\lim_{z\to0} \frac{f(z)}{1/z}=\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{f'(z)}{-1/z^2}=\lim_{z\to 0} -z^2f'(z)$$

Note that

$$\lim_{z\to 0} |-z^2f'(z)|\le \lim_{z\to0}|z|=0$$

Comment: You need not assume that $f\to \infty$ to apply LHR.

Comment: @MarkViola Wait, really? What do you mean?

Comment: LHR does not require that the numerator approach $\infty$ (in fact, the limit of the numerator need not even exist) when all of the smoothness conditions are met and the limit of the denominator is $\infty$.

Comment: @MarkViola Wow very cool, thanks for that! It makes my answer better.

Answer (score 1):

Set $\,g(z)=z\,f'(z)$. Clearly,
$$
|g(z)|=|z\,f'(z)|\le 1,
$$
and hence $g$ is bounded in the punctured unit disc $\mathbb D\setminus\{0\}$, and hence, $g$ has removable singularity at $z=0$, and consequently, $g$ extends analytically in the unit disc.

Expand $g$ in the unit disc as $g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$. Then
$$
f'(z)=\frac{a_0}{z}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1}z^n.
$$
Let $\gamma\subset\mathbb D\setminus\{0\}$ be a closed curve. Then 
$$
0=\int_{\gamma}\big(z\,f(z)\big)'\,dz=\int_{\partial B_r}\big(\,f(z)+z\,f'(z)\big)\,dz=\int_{\partial B_r}\big(\,f(z)+g(z)\big)\,dz=\int_{\partial B_r}f(z)\,dz.
$$
Hence, there exist an analytic function $F$ in $D\setminus\{0\}$, such that $F'=f$. Such an $F$ has a Laurent expansion of the form
$$
F(z)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z}b_kz^k
$$
and hence 
$$
f'(z)=F''(z)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z}k(k-1)b_kz^{k-2}.
$$
This implies that the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ is the expansion of $f'$ is $0$ and hence $a_0=0$, and thus $f$ is analytic in the disc.